# Trying to debug a WP_Query mixing taxonomies and meta fields

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to troubleshoot a WP_Query args array in which I mix taxonomies and metas.

I need to pass this to a plugin through a filter so I don't have full trnsparency over how it operates. However, when I needed to only stick to taxonomies, it worked as expected for WP_Query

For reference, this is an args array that works, over 2 custom taxonomies:

```
    array(3) {
  ["rv_time"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(9) "rv_time"
    ["field"]=>
    string(4) "name"
    ["terms"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "1990s"
    }
  }
  ["rv_subject"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(12) "rv_subject"
    ["field"]=>
    string(4) "name"
    ["terms"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "Alley"
    }
  }
  ["relation"]=>
  string(3) "AND"
}
```

This is the args array that **doesn't** work, having one taxonomy and the meta field I need

```
    array(3) {
  ["rv_places"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(20) "rv_place_hierarchy"
    ["meta_compare"]=>
    string(1) "LIKE"
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(6) "Paris"
  }
  ["rv_time"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(9) "rv_time"
    ["field"]=>
    string(4) "name"
    ["terms"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "1990s"
    }
  }
  ["relation"]=>
  string(3) "AND"
}
```

The rv_places bit is completely ignored, i.e. treated as an AND 1=1. the rv_place_hierarchy is present in the wp_postmeta table and the value I am looking for, too.

The expected behavior for this args array, is to find me the posts that have 1990s in their rv_time taxonomy AND contain the string Paris in rv_place_hierarchy.

Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the issue.

I was adding the meta query parameters at the wrong level in the array - inside the tax_query key.
I need to add the taxonomy queries to the tax_query key, and the meta query to the meta_query key.

So this is now a WP_Query args array that works for me

```
    array(9) {
    /* not relevant, it's just other parameters better qualifying the query - I leave them for context for anyone who needs more info figuring out where to insert their parameters
        ["post_type"]=>
        string(10) "attachment"
        ["post_mime_type"]=>
        array(4) {
        [0]=>
        string(5) "image"
        [1]=>
        string(8) "font/svg"
        [2]=>
        string(13) "image/svg+xml"
        [3]=>
        string(15) "application/pdf"
        }
        ["order"]=>
        string(3) "ASC"
        ["orderby"]=>
        string(10) "menu_order"
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(3) "any"
        ["exclude"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["numberposts"]=>
        int(-1)
        // end of "context" bit. from now on, the question-relevant bit
    */
        ["tax_query"]=>
        array(1) {
        ["rv_time"]=>
        array(3) {
            ["taxonomy"]=>
            string(9) "rv_time"
            ["field"]=>
            string(4) "name"
            ["terms"]=>
            array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(5) "1990s"
            }
        }
    }
        ["meta_query"]=>
        array(1) {
        ["rv_places"]=>
        array(3) {
            ["key"]=>
            string(20) "rv_place_hierarchy"
            ["compare"]=>
            string(4) "LIKE"
            ["value"]=>
            string(6) "Paris"
        }
    }
}
```